# (n.) 的大預言 having trouble making sense of this construct

Tags: meaning-in-context

So I have a person's name in place of the noun and I am trying to get a better handle on how to interpret this sentence. Would it be for example, Tommie's people predicted? The full context is that this is a chapter in a book:

Google translate gives me:

"...of people predicted"

Or could it be:

Predicted (n.) ?

Context: A Chapter title in the book I am reading:
哆啦 A 梦的大預言
Where the first part is just a name of the person in the book..

Based on comment's; it seems this would then be (n.) predictions.

The variations of the possessive do not seem to make sense to me in this context. Thanks in advance for any assistance resolving how to interpret this structure.

Comment: Can we get the noun?

Comment: @user3306356 Sure, its just a chapter heading in the book I am reading; 哆啦 A 梦的人預言 but I suppose any person's name could be used.

Comment: not to be a jerk - but are you sure it's not *哆啦A梦的大预言* -- 大 and not 人?

Comment: @user3306356 Good catch.. I don't understand the reasoning on the first part (of the comment) but now predicted becomes predictions and the context seems clear. I am only a beginner  (mistakes happen).

Comment: Yeah 的人预言 didn't make a lot of sense to me either! :)

Comment: @user3306356 I appreciate all answers that are helpful. I am trying to learn so that I can communicate with Chinese family members.

Comment: The title use 大预言 just because it translated from `ドラえもんの大予言`. I don't think this is native way to say in Chinese. It should only happened in Japanese - Chinese translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**的大预言**

预言 means *prophecy*

大 means *big*

预言 here most likely is **not** plural - hence the whole *的大*

---

edit: found this:

http://doraemon.wikia.com/wiki/Chapter_2:Prophecy_of_Doraemon

a chapter called "Prophecy of Doraemon" maybe it matches up to what you are reading...

[image]

Comment: Or "great prophecy"

Comment: My copy of the comic book is very old and in Chinese so sometimes the text is small but in this case I just made an error typing it out. Thanks!